# Why does this program segfault at argc argv?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

While trying to debug a fairly large program, I got a segmentation fault when creating a struct. For this reason I made another c file with a reduced version of the code to see if I could reproduce the crash, and noticed that the crash happens when I create a struct.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10000

typedef struct {
    char* type;
    char* name;
    int status;
}VARIABLE;

typedef struct {
    char* fun;
    char* t;
    char* args[SIZE];
}FUNCTION;

typedef struct {
    int gf;

    VARIABLE vars[SIZE];
    FUNCTION funs[SIZE];
}COMPILER;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    COMPILER compiler;
    return 0;
}
```

I solved the issue by substituting

`COMPILER compiler;`

with

`COMPILER* compiler = (COMPILER*)malloc(sizeof(COMPILER));`

The only thing that weirds me out is that when I tried to debug the first version of the code with gdb it gave me a segfault at argc and argv, with this message:

```
0x0000555555555160 in main (
    argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffd04abc4c>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffd04abc40>)
    at main.c:26
26  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
```

Why would it give me the segfault here and not at compiler's declaration? I'm not good with C yet and I'm trying to understand how to debug programs better. Thanks in advance

Comment: The stack explodes due to massive local variable requirement. There is `10000 * 10000` local allocation in there, even a 1-byte type would fail.

Comment: So lowering the SIZE would fix the error?

Comment: Yes, set `size` to say `10` instead of `10000`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I managed to fix various other problems inside the big problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: For larger arrays `malloc` is the way to go, if the system can provide. Always check its return value.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you make that an answer?

Comment: @thedemons I've marked it as a duplicate - this is a frequent type of question.